# finding the sum of two arrays elements that is equal to the input

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to iterate over an array to find two array items whose sum equals the target, not sure why isnt working

```js
const numsArr = [2,7,11,15]
const numTarget = 9

const  twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    const first = 0;
    const second = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=nums.length; i++){
        let tester = nums[i];
        if(tester + nums[i] == target){
          console.log('found it ')
            
            
        }else{
          console.log('i failed')
        }
    }
};
twoSum(numsArr, numsTarget)
```

Comment: You have a typo

Comment: Because you have your const named numTarget but call it as numTarget, with an extra S. Also always be sure to include the error message you get.

Comment: Also `tester = nums[i];` then you do `tester + nums[i] == target` so you add the same number *to itself*. You probably meant `tester + nums[i+1] == target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check for typo's: `numTarget` is not `numsTarget`; Furthermore, `break` the loop if the desired result is reached. Try something like:

```js
const log = Logger();

log(sumFromTarget([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
log(sumFromTarget([2, 7, 11, 15], 17));
log(sumFromTarget([1, 2, 3], 5)); // see comment

function sumFromTarget (nums, target) {
  let resultValues = [`nums => [${nums}], target => ${target}`];

  for (let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i += 1) {
    // determine if current value + next value
    // adds up to [target]
    const next = i < nums.length && nums[i] + nums[i + 1] === target;

    // if so, fill the result and stop processing
    if (next) {
      resultValues.push([nums[i], nums[i + 1]]);
      break;
    }
  }

  // return a result string (resultValues.length == 1: no result)
  return resultValues.length > 1 ?
    `${resultValues[0]}\n  Found a solution (${resultValues[1].join(" + ")} = ${target})` :
    `${resultValues[0]}\n  Could not find ${
      target} summing any of the consecutive values of the given array`;
}

function Logger() {
  const result = document.querySelector("#result") ||
    (() => {
      const rsltElem = Object.assign(
        document.createElement("pre"), 
        { id: "result" } );
      document.body.appendChild(rsltElem);
      return rsltElem;
    })();
    
  return (...args) => args.forEach(arg => result.textContent += `${arg}\n`);
}
```

Now if you want to find a certain sum from *any* of the values in the array, you have to do a bit more work. Something like:

```js
console.clear();
const numsArr = [2, 7, 11, 15];

const sumFromTarget = (nums, target) => {
  let nums2 = nums.slice();
  let resultValues = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i += 1) {
    const x = nums2.reduce((acc, n, ni) => {
      const runningTotal = ni > 0 ? acc[ni - 1][1] + n : n;
      
      if (runningTotal === target) {
        resultValues = nums2.slice(0, ni + 1);
      }
      
      if (n + nums[i] === target) {
        resultValues = [nums[i], n];
      }
      
      return [...acc, [n + nums[i], runningTotal]];
    }, []);

    const check = x.find(n => n[0] === target || n[1] === target);

    if (check) {
      console.log(`found a solution (${resultValues.join(" + ")})`);
      sum = target;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!resultValues.length) {
    console.log(`Could not reach ${
      target} summing any of the values of the given array`);
  }
}

sumFromTarget(numsArr, 9);
sumFromTarget(numsArr, 17);
sumFromTarget(numsArr, 13);
sumFromTarget(numsArr, 120);
```

Comment: While your function works, it's solving a *different* problem. OP wants to find if the sum of two consecutive elements anywhere in the array matching a target. Yours finds the sum of any amount of elements *as long as* they are sequential from the start. `sumFromTarget([1, 2, 3], 5)` will fail, for example, while OP's `twoSum([1, 2, 3], 5)` will instead print `"found it"` ([once appropriately fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476620/finding-the-sum-of-two-arrays-elements-that-is-equal-to-the-input#comment117520427_66476620))